# Objective-C: NSStrings dump, restricting debuggers & trace checking

Tags: objective-c, security, debugging, obfuscation, trace

I've been developing for Objective-C for some time now and one thing that really scares me is how easy it is to mess around with a compiled App and get information out using standard tools like the `strings` tool ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/strings.1.html)).

I've come around with some XOR based solutions to protect my strings that makes it more difficult to the average hacker to get into my program.

What else can I do to ensure the security in my sensitive strings?

Also, at runtime is it possible for me to check whether my App is currently being traced by a debugger or other debugging tool?